# Mongodb Install Path at windows

Tags: mongodb, advanced-installer

I am calling MongoDB installer from Advance installer as a prereq and making a windows service of MongoDB. If a user doesn't change default installation path of MongoDB every works fine.

If a user changes the installed path of MongoDB then I am not able to get installed path of MongoDB to make MongoDB server as windows service. Let's suppose user changes the default path to D:/Mongodb.

Could you please help me, where is installed path of MongoDB in windows registry or please suggest any other method to get the installed path of MongoDB on windows?

Comment: If the MongoDb installer can be launched silently, then you could install it silently, thus the user cannot change the default path. You can configure a silent command line for your MongoDb prereq from "prerequisites page of your setup project.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but my client didn't allow silent installation of MongoDB or any other reqreq.

Comment: Are you able to grab the MSI log once the Mongo pre-req is installed; what about having the user browse to the installation path if you can't find mongod.exe in the default installation location?  The install location for my MongoDB is blank in the Uninstall subkey, which is usually where I would direct you to look.

Comment: Thanks, I am following the same logic, I ask the user to select the MongoDB install path if can't find in the default location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install Mongodb silently(unintended install). You can change install location and other things by package parameters.

```
msiexec.exe /q /i mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl 3.6.4-signed.msi INSTALLLOCATION="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6.4\" ADDLOCAL="all" SHOULD_INSTALL_COMPASS="0"
```

In Advanced Installer, add MongoDb as prerequisite and then go to Setup Files tab. There set all 3 fields from "Install Command Lines" to:

> /qn INSTALLLOCATION="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6.4\"
>   ADDLOCAL="all" SHOULD_INSTALL_COMPASS="0"